# how to Customize the c++ delete

Tags: c++

I've written a function `myDelete` doing something similar to `delete`:

```
template<typename T>
void myDelete(T* p)
{
     /* do something */
     p->~T();
     free(p);
}
```

But when the parameter `p` is a pointer to a base class (subobject), there is an error when calling `free`.

Test code:

```
struct base0 
{
    int _;
    virtual ~base0() {}
};

struct base1 
{
    int _;
    virtual ~base1() {}
}

struct dev : public base0, public base1 
{
    int _;
    virtual ~dev() {}
}

base1* p = new dev();
myDelete(p);      // error, because p is adjust by base1
```

How to write the function `myDelete`?

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
void myDelete(T* p)
{
     /* do something */
    delete p;
}
```

This assumes p points to something allocated with new which is not an array.